Aggregate Jobs results in Jenkins using plugin like checkstyles, spotbugs and PMD
I'm trying to find a ay to aggregate all the results from all the jobs I'm running, I saw that such thing could be done via a plugin NAMED "Test Results Aggregator" but it seems like it only works for Junit, testNG, Nunit tests results, and all my jobs use checkstyles, PMD and spotbug instead...
Is there another way to do that, or way to configure the aggregator plugin so that it can be compatible with those test results?
Thanks
